# How Do I Sort A List Of Elements Into Numeric Order When I Have A Mix Of Integers And Strings?

Tags: python, list

I would like to order a list of elements which contain both integers and strings. I would like to order the list so that the biggest score comes first.

The list looks like this:

```py
winners = ["13, John", "8, Max", "15, Smith", "4, Bob"]
```

I have tried sorting the list in reverse with:

```py
winners.sort(reverse = True)
```

However, that did not work

I want the list to be:

```py
winners = ["15, Smith", "13, John", "8, Max", "4, Bob"]
```

Comment: `sorted(winners, key=lambda x: int(x.split(',')[0]), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
winners = ["13, John", "8, Max", "15, Smith", "4, Bob"]

# Use function key to control sort order
winners.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: int(x.split(',')[0]))
print(winners) # Result ['15, Smith', '13, John', '8, Max', '4, Bob']
```

Answer (score 0):

> a list of elements which contain both integers and strings

You don't have such a list; your list contains strings, and those strings happen to include comma-separated pairs of values, such that the first value is the *string representation of* an integer.

We can easily write a function that parses one of such strings to produce the corresponding pair (tuple):

```
def parse(item):
    x, y = item.split(',')
    return int(x), y
```

Then we can use this to sort the list according to the results of such parsing, by using the `key` argument of the built-in `sort`:

```
winners.sort(reverse=true, key=parse)
```

Comment: Your function will work if you just return `int(x)`.